# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]' when sending data to service

Tags: angular

I'm getting  error on this line
    this.apiService.getGifs(searchValue.value).subscribe(data=>this.results=data);

My code works but I'm getting this error so I want to figure out how to fix it. I believe it is becaouse of this part `.subscribe(data=>this.results=data);` but without it code doesn't work.

apiService

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

private results = new BehaviorSubject([]);

public getResults$(){
   return this.results.asObservable();
}

  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  link = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=';
  ApiKey = 'MaklOv0qiTVslRvJlBShgpr46LWPs5Z0';

  public getGifs(searchValue:string) {
     return this.http.get(this.link + searchValue +'&api_key='+ this.ApiKey)
     .map((res:Response) => this.results.next(res.json().data));
  }
}
```

Component which send data to service

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  results = []

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSearch(searchValue) {
   this.apiService.getGifs(searchValue.value).subscribe(data=>this.results=data);
  }
}
```

Component which receives data

```
export class OutputComponent implements OnInit {
  results = [];
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService){
    apiService.getResults$().subscribe(data => this.results = data)
}
```

Comment: Calling next on a subject doesn't return anything. You're trying to assign that nothing to an array-typed field. What is unclear from the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to what @jonrsharpe  said  this should work :

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

 public getGifs(searchValue:string) {
     return this.http.get(this.link + searchValue +'&api_key='+ this.ApiKey)
     .map((res:Response) => res.json().data)
     .do( data => this.results.next(data))
  }
```

Comment: @Allan it's better to not subscribe inside a service, see the update you have to import `do` operator.